# Assigning IAM Policy to an existing Cloud Build Service Account in Google cloud using terraform fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to assign a IAM policy document to an existing Cloud Build Service Account, but its failing for some reason.
following is my iam policy

```
data "google_iam_policy" "vulznotepolicy" {
binding {
  role = "roles/containeranalysis.notes.occurrences.viewer"

  members = [
  "serviceaccount:<project_number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
  ]
 }
}
```

following is policy assignment to Service account

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_policy" "buildsa" {
service_account_id = "serviceaccount:<project_number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
policy_data        = data.google_iam_policy.vulznotepolicy.policy_data
}
```

service account id doesn't accept the format that i have provided. I have given just the <project_number> still it doesn't accept. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: You are trying to add a role to the service account specifying the member which is the service account. Roles are added to the service account specifying another identity or added to the project, specifying the service account email as the identity. I think you want the second type. Review the CLI command `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding` to understand how to add roles for a service account to the project: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding The key is to understand the difference between a resource and an identity. A service account can be both

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Adding the Service account at the project level is the right approach. But it has its problems. Will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

As suggested rightly by John, i added the roles to the service account using the following

```
resource "google_project_iam_policy" "buildsa" {
project = var.project_id
policy_data        = data.google_iam_policy.vulznotepolicy.policy_data
}
```

Although this works but can cause serious problems as follows. Please proceed with caution

> Since this is an authoritative operation, it will lock you out of your account if the operations are not carefully managed. This is from terraform "It's not recommended to use google_project_iam_policy with your provider project to avoid locking yourself out, and it should generally only be used with projects fully managed by Terraform. If you do use this resource, it is recommended to import the policy before applying the change."

Answer (score -3):

I can see that you’re trying to give the Cloud Build Service account some IAM permissions using Terraform.

I would start by reading this document about IAM Roles on Cloud Build [1], then you can check how the Cloud Build Service Account behaves [2], and then how to configure it [3].

Since you’re using Terraform, I would also have a look here [4].

These can help you understand why you’re running into this issue, as pointed out in a comment.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/iam-roles-permissions

[2] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-build-service-account

[3] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#before_you_begin

[4] https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account_iam.html

Comment: i have gone through most of them before writing terraform code. But it still doesn't solve the specific issue.

Comment: @CarloC. thank you for the links, but it does not help with the very specific question. Can you just give a hint what's wrong?